# PEG grammar not working as expected

Tags: parsing, clojure, peg

I'm working on a PEG grammar that takes code in a Music Programming Language and creates a parse tree of musical events (notes, chords, volume/tempo changes, etc.). A feature of my MPL is that it supports voices, i.e. different sequences of events happening at the same time. I'm having a hard time getting my [Instaparse](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse) grammar to parse this correctly... what I want is a `voices` tag that consists of one or more `voice`s, each of which consists of a voice definition (e.g. `V1:`) and then any number of events. The `voices` tag should end either with `V0:` (which means the end of the split voices, and we're back to just one voice, or "voice zero"), or the end of the file.

Here is an excerpt of my grammar in progress (I'm leaving out the definitions of `note`, `chord`, etc. for the sake of clarity):

```
part                    = <ows> event+
<event>                 = chord | note | rest | octave-change |
                          attribute-change | voices |
                          marker | at-marker

voices                  = voice+ 
voice                   = !voices voice-number voice-events? 
                          (<voice-zero> | #"\z")
voice-number            = <"V"> #"[1-9]\d*" <":"> <ows>
<voice-zero>            = <"V0:"> <ows>
voice-events            = !voices event+ 

...

ows                     = #"\s*"
```

Given the following code:

```
V1: o2 b1/>b o2 g+/>g+ o2 g/>g 
V0: e8 f+ g+ a b2
```

Running the parser gives the following output:

```
[:part 
  [:voices 
    [:voice [:voice-number "1"] 
            [:voice-events 
              [:octave-change "2"] [:chord [:note [:pitch "b"] 
              [:duration "1"]] [:octave-change ">"] [:note [:pitch "b"]]] 
              [:octave-change "2"] [:chord [:note [:pitch "g+"]] 
              [:octave-change ">"] [:note [:pitch "g+"]]] 
              [:octave-change "2"] [:chord [:note [:pitch "g"]]
              [:octave-change ">"] [:note [:pitch "g"]]]]]] 
  [:note [:pitch "e"] [:duration "8"]] 
  [:note [:pitch "f+"]] 
  [:note [:pitch "g+"]] 
  [:note [:pitch "a"]] 
  [:note [:pitch "b"] [:duration "2"]]]
```

Which is exactly what I want. The `V0:` signals the end of the `voices` tag, and the last 5 notes are on their own inside the `part` tag.

However, when I change the `V0` to `V2`, I get this:

```
[:part 
  [:voices 
    [:voice [:voice-number "1"] 
            [:voice-events 
              [:octave-change "2"] [:chord [:note [:pitch "b"] [:duration "1"]] 
              [:octave-change ">"] [:note [:pitch "b"]]] [:octave-change "2"] 
              [:chord [:note [:pitch "g+"]] [:octave-change ">"] 
              [:note [:pitch "g+"]]] [:octave-change "2"] 
              [:chord [:note [:pitch "g"]] [:octave-change ">"] 
              [:note [:pitch "g"]]] 
              [:voices 
                [:voice [:voice-number "2"] 
                [:voice-events 
                  [:note [:pitch "e"] [:duration "8"]] [:note [:pitch "f+"]] 
                  [:note [:pitch "g+"]] [:note [:pitch "a"]] 
                  [:note [:pitch "b"] [:duration "2"]]]]]]]]]
```

For some reason, either the `voice` 1 tag or its `voice-events` tag is not terminating like it's supposed to, and the second `voice` is swallowed up as part of the first `voice`'s `voice-events`. I also don't want there to be a second `voices` tag; `voice` 2 should be within the primary `voices` tag.

What I want is this:

```
[:part 
  [:voices 
    [:voice [:voice-number "1"] 
            [:voice-events 
              [:octave-change "2"] [:chord [:note [:pitch "b"] [:duration "1"]] 
              [:octave-change ">"] [:note [:pitch "b"]]] [:octave-change "2"] 
              [:chord [:note [:pitch "g+"]] [:octave-change ">"] 
              [:note [:pitch "g+"]]] [:octave-change "2"] 
              [:chord [:note [:pitch "g"]] [:octave-change ">"] 
              [:note [:pitch "g"]]]]]
    [:voice [:voice-number "2"] 
            [:voice-events 
              [:note [:pitch "e"] [:duration "8"]] [:note [:pitch "f+"]] 
              [:note [:pitch "g+"]] [:note [:pitch "a"]] 
              [:note [:pitch "b"] [:duration "2"]]]]]]
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, but I think it has something to do with how I'm defining the `voice` tag and/or the `voice-events` tag. It may have something to do with how I'm using negative lookahead, which I don't think I fully understand yet. Can anyone figure out how I can fix my grammar?

Thanks! :)

## Solved!

Thanks, @DanielNeal! I've re-worked my grammar to this, which works exactly the way I want it to:

```
part                    = <ows> (voices | event)+
<event>                 = chord | note | rest | octave-change |
                          attribute-change | marker | at-marker

voices                  = voice+ (<voice-zero> | <#"\z">)
voice                   = voice-number event*
voice-number            = <"V"> #"[1-9]\d*" <":"> <ows>
<voice-zero>            = <"V0:"> <ows>

...

ows                     = #"\s*"
```

The big change was in how I defined `part` and `event`; before, I had these terms defined such that `voices` is an event, so any subsequent `voice`s were being consumed and lumped into the previous `voice`'s `event`s. By pulling `voices` out of the definition of an `event` and redefining `part` to be a variable number of `voices` groupings or `event`s, I eliminated the ambiguity and got the grammar to behave the way I want it to.

After that, the `events` within a `voice` were grouping properly, but I was still having a problem with each voice being within its own separate `voices` tag, when I need them to all be within the same `voices` grouping. I fixed this by specifying that a `voices` tag ends either with a `"V0:"` or the end of the file (`\z`), in other words being more specific about how much code I want the `voices` tag to consume.

The moral of the story is, if you're writing a PEG grammar and you're having problems, you probably need to make your definitions less ambiguous! I also ended up not using negative lookahead at all, which I think helped a lot to simplify / de-ambiguify my grammar.

Comment: Might be a missing line Terminator (or whatever '\z' represented) at end of the Second line in your sample.

Comment: Wouldn't \z be the end of the string? The input is passed in as a string, like `"V1: o2 b1/>b o2 g+/>g+ o2 g/>g\nV2: e8 f+ g+ a b2"`

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry. Actually your grammar is ambiguous for `V1-9` - the grammar Production for Voice allows for empty voice-events which is exactly what you observe.  This problem does not occur with `V0` is the Last V-Clause of your input.

Comment: That's intentional -- I wanted to allow for cases like `"V1: c d e\nV2:"`, which I want to be parsed as `[:part [:voices [:voice [:voice-number "1"] [:voice-events [:note [:pitch "c"]] [:note [:pitch "d"]] [:note [:pitch "e"]]]] [:voice [:voice-number "2"]]]]`. At any rate, I tried making `voice-events` mandatory by removing the `?`, but it didn't make any difference. I think my problem has something to do with not terminating the `voice` and/or `voice-events` tags properly... it seems like they are acting greedily. By the way, my output just changed mysteriously... I'm going to update above.

Comment: Edited. Now my problem is more straightforward, although still perplexing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're right - it's the negative lookahead that's causing the problem. 
Without your full grammar, I can't test properly, but this line:

```
voice-events = !voices event+
```

Represents something that does not match `voices` **followed by** one or more `events`.

I'm assuming that `voice-events` should not contain `voices` within it in a recursive way, but at the moment it does - indirectly. Each`event` can contain `voices` within it, and in turn, `voice-events` can contain `events`.

In the sample above, the first event in V1 is an octave shift (which matches the not-a-voice condition). This allows the subsequent voice that occurs to get consumed within the `event` definition. If that makes sense.

To fix this you could (perhaps) define it the other way round:

```
voice-event = chord | note | rest | octave-change | attribute-change | marker | at-marker
event       = voice-event | voices
```

Comment: A-ha! That makes perfect sense -- thank you for the explanation. I guess I was misunderstanding how negative lookahead works. I'm going to re-define my grammar to be something like the above and try it tonight. I have a feeling this will fix it.

Comment: Yep, that worked! I had to make a couple other tweaks, too, to make my grammar less ambiguous. I posted the working version as an edit to my question, in case you're curious. Thanks again for your help!